# How to make background image with aspect ratio in html and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have read many question on stackoverflow but couldn't find better answer for adding image with auto height and width :

here is example what i am trying to do :

visit : http://www.teleclub.ch

In this website when we resize window image auto positioned left and right not exactly resize.

So can any one tell me how i can do this ?

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: no this is not i am looking for, it's very basic and i know this i want aspect ratio like in website link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size:cover` + `background-position:center` actually will do the trick:

[**JsFiddle** (drag the borders around to see)](http://jsfiddle.net/4A3n9/)

Comment: Thanks,but does it work with div too if i put div size to 100% in height and width ?

Comment: Yes it does (http://jsfiddle.net/4A3n9/1/)